# Component not picking env variable

Tags: reactjs

I have defined `HOMEPAGE_URL=/home` in `.env`.

I am using it in `App.js` (I tried to call it both inside and outside `function App()`.

```
...
const dotenv = require('dotenv')

dotenv.config()

import './App.css';
function App() {

const [data, setData] = useState({}); //initial value is an empty object

useEffect(() => { 
  fetch(HOMEPAGE_URL) 
...
```

I created a test case in `app.test.js`

```
...
const dotenv = require('dotenv')


beforeAll(()=>{
  dotenv.config()

})
...
describe("home page test cases", ()=>{

  it('renders homepage content', async () => { 
    render(<App />);
    expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(await screen.findByText("welcome")).toBeInTheDocument()
  });  
  
})
```

The test case fails with error

```
home page test cases › renders homepage content                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                     
    ReferenceError: HOMEPAGE_URL is not defined                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                     
      22 |                                                                                                                           
      23 | useEffect(() => {                                                                                                         
    > 24 |   fetch(HOMEPAGE_URL) 
         |         ^
      25 |     .then((res) => {
      26 |       console.log(`got response: ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
      27 |       return res.json();  //return json from res
```

Why is `HOMEPAGE_URL` undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dotenv` package loads the variables defined in `.env` into `process.env`.
To access, you have to use `process.env.HOMEPAGE_URL` instead of `HOMEPAGE_URL`.

Refer the NPM package: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv?activeTab=readme#:~:text=Dotenv%20is%20a%20zero%2Ddependency%20module%20that%20loads%20environment%20variables%20from%20a%20.env%20file%20into%20process.env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv?activeTab=readme#:%7E:text=Dotenv%20is%20a%20zero%2Ddependency%20module%20that%20loads%20environment%20variables%20from%20a%20.env%20file%20into%20process.env).

Answer (score 1):

I think is just define the environment constant like:

```
const HOMEPAGE_URL = process.env.HOMEPAGE_URL
```

Above the fetch function and it will work.

The `dotenv` just work like an environment file control, and will select the `.env` file you set on cli command but to access this variable, you still need to use 'process.env.(env name)' in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Vite, this is from the documentation [Docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html)

To prevent accidentally leaking env variables to the client, only variables prefixed with VITE_ are exposed to your Vite-processed code. e.g. for the following env variables:

```
VITE_SOME_KEY=123
DB_PASSWORD=foobar
```

Only VITE_SOME_KEY will be exposed as import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_KEY to your client source code, but DB_PASSWORD will not.

```
console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_KEY) // 123
console.log(import.meta.env.DB_PASSWORD) // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

When using [Create-React-App](https://create-react-app.dev/), it's essential to prefix your environment variables with `REACT_APP_`. Failure to do so will result in the variables not being injected. [Source](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#expanding-environment-variables-in-env)

If you're using [VITE](https://vitejs.dev/), ensure that your variables are prefixed with `VITE_`. Keep in mind that this configuration can be customized via the `vite.config` file. [Source](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html)

In both cases, the `.env` file is parsed automatically (dotenv not required). For example, `HOMEPAGE_URL` won't work as expected; it must be prefixed accordingly, such as `REACT_APP_HOMEPAGE_URL`.

This is crucial because file building is an OS-level operation, and it grants access to all environment variables. Among these variables, there may be sensitive data. React's approach is to filter out data that should be incorporated into the built script, as the built script is public and visible to everyone, and sensitive data cannot be injected.